# javascript setInterval dont see .css jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this small peace of `js` code:

```
var config = $('.fullscreen_src');
var i=0;
function display_images(){
    i++;
    var image = config[i % config.length];
    image.css('display', 'block');
}
setInterval(display_images, 3000);
```

and it throws error every 3 sec because of `delay`. The error is this `TypeError: image.css is not a function` and i don't know what cuse it. When i change `function display_image` to this:

```
function display_images(){
    i++;
    alert('tralal ' + i);
}
```

it's working fine, why ?

Comment: css is function of Jquery object. wrap the object inside $(image)

Comment: just a note that use of `setInterval` is discouraged; it is far better to use `setTimeout`, with a repeated call inside the function. See [this page](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts) for a detailed explaination of why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function display_images(){
    i++;
    var image = config[i % config.length];
    $(image).css('display', 'block');  // Use jQuery object..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Jquery Object which contains the `css` function

```
function display_images(){
    i++;
    var image = $(config[i % config.length]);
    image.css('display', 'block');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

css is function of Jquery object. wrap the object inside $(image), try like this

```
function display_images(){
    i++;
    var image = $(config[i % config.length]); // now image is Jquery object, so you can access CSS methods 
    image.css('display', 'block');
}
```

or 
you can wrap the image object with jquery

```
 $(image).css('display', 'block');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code like this.

```
var image = config[i % config.length];
image = $(image);
image.css('display', 'block');
```